# WHERE id = (SELECT parent_id FROM sametable LIMIT 1)

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

It's basically a radio button behavior but for database.

I have table `galleries` and table `images`

`images` has `image_id`, `gallery_id` and `featured` columns

```
1 | 55 | true
2 | 55 | false
3 | 55 | false
4 | 54 | true
```

There should be only one featured image per gallery. My function should take `image_id` for the new featured image - set `featured` to true and old `featured` to false...

How do I set the old featured image of that gallery to false and the new one to true just for that particular gallery. (I only want to provide the id of the image not the `gallery_id`.)

I was thinking of using 2 queries: one to unset the current, one to set the new

I couldn't get even the first one to work. Here's what I tried:

```
UPDATE `images` SET `featured` = 0 WHERE `featured` = 1 
AND `page_id` = (SELECT `page_id` FROM `images` WHERE `image_id` = :image_id LIMIT 1)
```

That doesn't work for some reason. There can't be another `where` i think...

Thanks!

Comment: Set them all to false. Then set the true one to true. Do it as a transaction.

Comment: use a trigger on your database...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE `images`
   SET `featured` = IF(image_id = :image_id, 1, 0)
 WHERE `gallery_id` = :gallery_id
```

so you simply reset the images for a given gallery into a desired state.

The `IF(image_id = :image_id, 1, 0)` expression returns `1` if the `image_id` matches the given `:image_id` or `0` otherwise.

One that prefers ANSII SQL over mysql's SQL dialect might use

```
CASE image_id WHEN :image_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

instead.

If you don't want to pass the `gallery_id` explicitly you may select it in the same query:

```
WHERE `gallery_id` IN (SELECT gallery_id FROM
                (SELECT gallery_id FROM images WHERE image_id = :image_id) x)
```

note there are **2** nested queries. You need that to fool mysql, since it does not allow accessing the same table from a DML query.

Comment: That's nice but: "I only want to provide the id of the image not the gallery_id"

Comment: @miro I added explanation on how to do that with a subquery

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I couldn't get... the double select thing... Thanks a lot! You rock